# Unable to set a sprite velocity under if(isTouching()) block

Tags: javascript, code.org

```
    var player = createSprite(320,390,20,20);
    var wall1 = createSprite(220,360,210,20);
    var wall2 = createSprite(180,300,210,20);

    createEdgeSprites();

    wall1.velocityX = 2;
    wall2.velocityX = -2;




    function draw() {
      background("white");
      if(keyWentDown("space")&&player.velocityY==0){
        player.velocityY = -10;
      }
 
      player.velocityY += 0.8;

      if(keyDown("left")){
        player.x-=5;
      }
      if(keyDown("right")){
        player.x+=5;
      }


      if(player.isTouching(wall1)){
        player.velocityX = wall1.velocityX;
        console.log("Player velocity: "+player.velocityX);
        console.log("Wall1 velocity: "+wall1.velocityX);
      }
      else{
        player.velocityX = 0;
      }
      if(player.isTouching(wall2)){
        player.velocityX = wall2.velocityX;
        console.log("Player velocity: "+player.velocityX);
        console.log("Wall2 velocity: "+wall2.velocityX);
      } 
      wall1.bounceOff(edges);
      wall2.bounceOff(edges);

      player.collide(edges);
      player.collide(wall1);
      player.collide(wall2);
      drawSprites();
    }
```

I am trying this maze project in code.org's gamelab. I want the speed of movement of player to be same as that of the wall. The velocities displayed in console point to same numbers, but I believe that the player.collide(wall) instruction is causing the difference in the speed between player and wall. Can someone help me to overcome this? If I don't give collide option, how can I make the player stand on the walls and assign same velocity as that of wall?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in one tiny piece of code:

```
else {
    player.velocityX = 0;
}
```

That pesky little `else` statement was what was causing that problem. You see, your else statement said that if `player` is touching `wall1`, then give them the same velocity. The thing is, the `else` is unnecessary.

The `draw()` function 50 times per second (I changed the frame rate),  every time it is executed, it checks whether the `if` statement is true. If it is not true, the code within the `if` statement is not executed.  The `else` statement is executed if the player is not. touching `wall1`, which includes whenever it's touching `wall2` or not touching anything. That means that once you land on wall2 (the bottom one) every frame, the engine. gets confused about whether to set `player`'s velocity to 0 or that of `wall2`, and for some reason, sets it to the negative of the velocity of `wall2`. Remove that statement, and it works just fine.

Here is the final project with some edits:

[Floaty Maze](https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/Sk8HL-KuRFmj0KwEkcKA1kQYgoil0U5ciJAVesSnlKI)

***Hope this helped!***